# MariaDB Out of memory

Tags: mysql, apache, out-of-memory, mariadb, administration

My database crash with out of memory error ~1-2 times per day. Last crash was at 17:30 in logs and at 19:30 in metrics (different timezones).

Errors in mariadb.log:

```
181120 16:09:00 [Warning] IP address '185.156.177.144' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
181120 16:35:40 [Warning] IP address '58.221.58.248' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
181120 17:30:38 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
181120 17:30:38 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
181120 17:30:41 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
181120 17:30:41 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-MariaDB) starting as process 16636 ...
181120 17:30:41 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 70  table_cache: 472
181120 17:30:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
181120 17:30:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
181120 17:30:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
181120 17:30:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
181120 17:30:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 150.0M
181120 17:30:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
181120 17:30:42 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
181120 17:30:42  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
181120 17:30:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
181120 17:30:47 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.49-MariaDB-38.0 started; log sequence number 18741266161
181120 17:30:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
181120 17:30:48 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
181120 17:30:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
181120 17:30:49 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.52-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
181120 17:30:53 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './admin_wikis/wp_posts' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
181120 17:30:53 [Warning] Checking table:   './admin_wikis/wp_posts'
181120 17:31:58 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
181120 17:31:58 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
181120 17:32:01 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
181120 17:32:01 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.52-MariaDB) starting as process 16899 ...
181120 17:32:01 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 70  table_cache: 472
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 150.0M
InnoDB: mmap(161447936 bytes) failed; errno 12
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
181120 17:32:01 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
181120 17:32:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
181120 17:32:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
181120 17:32:01 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
181120 17:32:01 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
181120 17:32:01 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
181120 17:32:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
181120 17:32:02 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
181120 17:32:02 [ERROR] Aborting

181120 17:32:02 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

There is nothing interesing in apache log in this time. Event requests count

```
$ sudo grep -r "GET \/" /etc/httpd/logs/domains/ |  cut -d' ' -f4 | sed 's/\[//;s/\]//;s/\"//' | cut -d':' -f1-2 | sort | uniq -c

459 19/Nov/2018:03
426 19/Nov/2018:04
239 19/Nov/2018:05
350 19/Nov/2018:06
381 19/Nov/2018:07
415 19/Nov/2018:08
778 19/Nov/2018:09
500 19/Nov/2018:10
450 19/Nov/2018:11
633 19/Nov/2018:12
458 19/Nov/2018:13
527 19/Nov/2018:14
713 19/Nov/2018:15
654 19/Nov/2018:16
573 19/Nov/2018:17
413 19/Nov/2018:18
471 19/Nov/2018:19
499 19/Nov/2018:20
661 19/Nov/2018:21
452 19/Nov/2018:22
773 19/Nov/2018:23
934 20/Nov/2018:00
295 20/Nov/2018:01
369 20/Nov/2018:02
441 20/Nov/2018:03
384 20/Nov/2018:04
927 20/Nov/2018:05
524 20/Nov/2018:06
972 20/Nov/2018:07
612 20/Nov/2018:08
609 20/Nov/2018:09
677 20/Nov/2018:10
753 20/Nov/2018:11
615 20/Nov/2018:12
717 20/Nov/2018:13
474 20/Nov/2018:14
973 20/Nov/2018:15
510 20/Nov/2018:16
534 20/Nov/2018:17
415 20/Nov/2018:18
 90 20/Nov/2018:19
```

I get some metrics:

Processes before crash: 
[image: Processes before crash]

Processes in the moment of crash:
[image: Processes in the moment of crash]

Memory and CPU usage:

[image: Memory and CPU usage]

Total RAM 3.6G. Does someone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

- `httpd` is the largest memory user; decrease its settings, especially the number of 'children' it is willing to spawn.  (Under 10 should suffice for most small installations.)
- `max_connections: 70  table_cache: 472` -- Cut each of those in half; this will help a little with memory allocation.
- Next time the CPU hits 100%, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` in MySQL.  That may give you a clue of what runaway queries you have.  Then we can focus on them.  If that fails, turn on the slowlog; it will catch some of them.
- Consider moving to an 8GB server.  (Is this a cloud server?)

Comment: Thanks. Will try today. But I think CPU and memory load at "Processes in the moment of crash" looks very strange

Comment: "Under 10 should suffice" ha ha ha ha ha!

Comment: @symcbean - If you need more than N (eg, 10), then the threads will stumble over each other and pile up.  Sure, they will all be "running", but in reality they will mostly be stalled waiting for CPU/swap/IO/MySQL/etc.  Throughput will hit some limit, and latency will go through the roof.  And, guess what, you get graphs like those.

Comment: Have you ever been in a store where there were so many people that it was hard to move your cart around?  Some stores are wise to that (or maybe threatened by the Fire Marshall) and nave you wait at the door, letting people in gradually.

Comment: http://www.stdlib.net/~colmmacc/Apachecon-EU2005/scaling-apache-handout.pdf (I have personally ran LAMP boxes with much lower specs handling 500+ concurrent connections)

Comment: More significant than "concurrent connections" is the `STATUS` value `Threads_running`.  Even 50 (on 5.5) for that value is likely to indicate imminent "crash".  I have seen a 2GB server hum along fine with over 1000 concurrent connections -- but Threads_running was low.

Comment: @symcbean - "Under 10" -- speed up the web pages and you won't need even 10.  Apache is quite happy to keep the excess waiting to get in.  Imagine a grocery store with 1000 people in it.  It would take forever to get out.  It is better to wait outside until there is some maneuvering room.